# Dask tokenizing error in CSV read because of fields containing CRLF (windows new lines)

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I use dask to read a csv with lines ended by LF (`\n`) but with some multi-lines fields containing CRLF (`\r\n`)

Example:

```
1234;Hello;47
1235;"Muli  <====\r\n here
line        <====\r\n here
field";42
1236;World;43
```

It does not fail on all `\r\n` but when it does I get:
`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 2874`

```py
data_frame = dd.read_csv(filename, encoding=encoding, delimiter=";",
                         header=0, quotechar='"', doublequote=True,
                         escapechar="\\", lineterminator='\n', 
                         dtype=dtypes, **kwargs)
```

- The same file works with pandas read_csv but I have to use Dask because it is faster
- I tried multiple blocksize values (default, 64M and None), all failed
- I tried to specify `\n` and `\r\n` as `lineterminator` parameter, both failed

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

(I suspect this must have. duplicate, but I haven't tried to find it yet)

Dask reads each block of your data from the file independently. Within each bytes offset, it first reads to the following `"\n"` before starting to parse, to get whole lines. That means there is *no way* to tell whether a `"\n"` character is within a quoted string or not - the only way to know that is to parse from the start of the file.

To work around this, you would need to write some custom loading logic to look for \r\n and ignore them (but what if this happens right on the boundary?), or do a first run through the file to find offsets that you know are good. Generally people do not use blocked loading on your type of file at all.

Comment: I have read an answer like yours in a SO thread but why a blocksize set to None does not work as it should read the whole file in a single block?